# Is the "Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act" already valid?

Tags: usa, legal, us-visa-waiver-program

I'd like to visit the USA in four weeks and recently read about the "Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act" which disallows people who visited Iran since 2011 to travel to the USA without a visa.

Does this already apply? If not, when will it apply?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may have heard of talk about [H.R. 158](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/158), the "Visa Waiver Program Improvement Act of 2015" (which may also be referred to as the "Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act of 2015"), which has not been passed by Congress, but you are really looking at the wrong bill. This bill has not passed because it is no longer being considered. Congress decided to pass the provisions through a different bill because politics is confusing like that.

Changes to the Visa Waiver Program have indeed been recently passed, as part of [H.R. 2029](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/2029), the "Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2016" (the "Omnibus" bill), and was signed into law by the President on December 18, 2015. The changes to VWP are in [Division O, Section 203](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/2029/text#toc-H817E7A09DD2C47BFA0E019C5C89DDFB7) of the bill. The gist of it is that people who have traveled to Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan since Mar 1, 2011, or who have the nationality of Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan (regardless of whether they have ever been to that country), are disqualified from using the Visa Waiver Program.

People who don't use the Visa Waiver Program are not affected by these changes. (For example, some countries are not part of the VWP but their nationals can visit the US without a visa: e.g. Canada, Federated States of Micronesia, Palau, Marshall Islands, and, obviously, the US.)

---

**Update:** The US announced that it will [begin implementing the changes](http://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/01/21/united-states-begins-implementation-changes-visa-waiver-program) on January 21, 2016. It says that people who currently hold ESTAs who have indicated having one of those 4 nationalities will have their ESTAs revoked. It says that the Secretary can waive the restrictions for certain reasons but it's not clear where in the ESTA process such a waiver would be applied for.

Comment: Would you mind quoting where you find people with iranian citizienship being disqualified? I can only see Iraq and Syria.

Comment: @Kia Consult the list of [State-department designated State Sponsors of Terrorism](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/list/c14151.htm), which comprise Iran, Sudan, and Syria.

Comment: Guess I can cancel my trip then..thanks for information.

Comment: @Kia Or apply for a visa.

Comment: I wanted to fly in 4 weeks and I do not have enough money to pay the fees.

Comment: @Kia the act has been signed into law but AFAIK *it has not yet been implemented.* The last I heard was that it would take effect later this year.

Comment: I'll just try my luck and apply for ESTA. The worst they could do is arrest me in USA or something..or kill me.

Comment: @Kia I would do that if I were you.  I doubt they can start enforcing the law before they can modify their systems and update the content of their informational web sites to reflect the new eligibility requirement.  If I find anything that specifically discusses the timing of implementation, I will post an answer to your question.

Comment: Does that mean the law is already in effect or not?

Comment: @Relaxed: I couldn't find anything about that

Comment: @Relaxed This [article](http://www.elpasotimes.com/story/news/immigration/blogs/immigration-in-focus/2015/12/21/visa-waiver-program-restrictions-coming-soon/77703242/) claims the restrictions might be active (since Dec '15), but [an article about the VWP changes in this week's Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21684791-governments-are-deterring-business-travellers-and-tourists-cumbersome-visa-requirements), dated Jan 2, uses the future tense and says "in 2016 America will start requiring [the discussed] visas..."

Comment: [travel.state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) has some info about the changes that you could add to your answer.

Comment: @Relaxed: I have added an update

Comment: @Kia sadly, "later this year" appears to be yesterday, with precious little notice.  I am very sorry.

Comment: Just got the mail. http://i.imgur.com/hnBgo08.png

Comment: @Kia: The good news is that there seems to be decent support in Congress for undoing the part of the changes regarding dual nationals: http://www.politico.com/story/2016/01/congress-visa-waiver-iran-iraq-syria-sudan-217714

Answer (score 6):

Not yet, and it might never apply - but to keep tabs on it:

[H.R.158 - Visa Waiver Program Improvement Act of 2015](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/158) - the bill's current state.

It's passed the house, and has been received by the Senate, but hasn't been voted on there yet.

[As many have observed](http://thehill.com/blogs/congress-blog/foreign-policy/263661-visa-waiver-program-improvement-act-short-on-prevention), let alone tourists to the US, it may create two classes of US citizens, for those who have visited Iran.

As a result, it might be ruled unconstitutional, but we'll see. Stranger things have happened.

As a NZ citizen who visited Iran last year, I'm also watching it with interest and alarm.

Comment: Just because that bill did not pass does not mean that changes to VWP have not been passed.

Comment: @user102008 please re-read and consider your vote.  1) I didn't say it hasn't passed.  It's in progress - if you'd clicked the link, you'd see that too.  It might well pass!  2) if you followed the second link, and read what it said, it can actually affect them if they're dual nationals.  I specifically said "let alone tourists to the US...".

Comment: (Of course, in terms of bills passing etc, I'm a NZ citizen, not a US legal expert, and am merely an interested traveller)

Comment: @MarkMayo: Wow, the year is only four days old and you've already managed to squeeze in a visit to Iran!

Comment: @hippietrail well spotted ;)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the opportunity to exercise my sarcasm (-:

Comment: @MarkMayo: That particular bill hasn't passed and is not going to pass because the changes to VWP have already been enacted into law (not through that bill). This was actually big news last month.

Comment: @user102008, quite a lot of visa regulations are based on reciprocity. If the US changes the rules on dual-nationality foreigners, foreign contries might change the rules on dual-nationality Americans.

Comment: @o.m.: oh now I get what he meant; he means for entry to other countries

Comment: @user102008 Actually, the news I read (e.g. [from the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-35162916)) made it sound like something that will be implemented later this year. Is it the case or not?

Comment: @Relaxed yes, it was the case.  Later this year apparently was yesterday, less than a month after that article was written.

Answer (score 3):

These changes are not yet in effect.  They will not take effect without an announcement.  See, for example, http://america.aljazeera.com/articles/2015/12/30/changes-to-visa-waiver-program-could-impact-ngos1.html:

> The changes have yet to be put into practice, according to the Department of Homeland Security (DHS), which is responsible for implementing the VWP provisions.
>
> “At this time, no determination has been made as to how the waiver provision would be implemented,” DHS representative S.Y. Lee said in a statement. “We will announce any changes affecting travelers to the United States from visa waiver program countries as soon as that information is available.”
>
> The DHS has not provided details on when that information will be available or indicated if exceptions will be made for aid workers.

**UPDATE, 22 January 2016:**

Unfortunately, it appears that the announcement was made yesterday, with immediate effect.  Earlier assurances that "an announcement would be made," implying that people would have adequate notice to adjust their travel plans, appear to have been disingenuous or incompetent.