# How can the US immigration officials know one has visited Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Now that [H.R. 2029](http://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/01/21/united-states-begins-implementation-changes-visa-waiver-program) is in effect, people who have visited Iraq, Syria, Iran, or Sudan since 2011 are banned from entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program. However it's unclear to me how could the US officials prove one has set foot in those countries, unless:

- There's a stamp in one's passport indicating so, which can be side-stepped by getting a fresh passport
- One mentions the fact on the ESTA application form, which is obviously easy to avoid

Is there any other way the US might be able to identify such individuals?

**NB:** I'm not eligible for the VWP myself and don't plan to travel to the four countries above, so it's a purely theorethical question

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/is-the-visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-alr

Comment: Generally lying on an official form is *not* recommended.

Comment: The link you provided does not lead to relevant information.

Comment: You are probably looking for this link http://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/01/21/united-states-begins-implementation-changes-visa-waiver-program

Comment: @MarkMayo plenty of people lie to Iran about their travel history to Israel, I assume plenty will lie about the reverse as well.

Comment: @JonathanReez does it mean they passed a law they cannot enforce?

Comment: @GayotFow I'm afraid only law-abiding citizens will be affected, just like with many other "anti-terrorist" laws

Comment: @GayotFow I think you summarized the question. How _will_ they check if you're telling the truth?

Comment: Well; if you'ev ever flown to/from the US from those countries, tehy'd probably know. Possibly also if you've flown to/from other five-eyes nations to those places as well.

Comment: Possibly related, in the sense that it's about trying to fool the US: [What's the value of the “genocide” and similar questions on the US customs form I-94?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/whats-the-value-of-the-genocide-and-similar-questions-on-the-us-customs-form)

Comment: They can't prove but they will defiantly know because they spy on everyone, it's the same result tho because they can lie as usual and refuse to let you in for any reason. God bless the queen we are in heaven compared to the states.

Comment: It hasn't taken effect yet.  Nobody is banned from using the VWP. "Important Notice: The Department of Homeland Security has begun the process of implementing changes to the traveler eligibility requirements of the Visa Waiver Program mandated by the Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act of 2015, as enacted on December 18, 2015.  The Department of Homeland Security will announce any changes affecting travelers to the United States from Visa Waiver Program countries as soon as that information is available."

Comment: @phoog from linked article: "Beginning January 21, 2016,...."

Comment: [And it's already affected some in the news](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3408633/BBC-journalist-barred-travelling-family-dual-British-Iranian-nationality.html)

Comment: And as someone who went to Iran in July/August for a wedding and tourism, I'm a touch bitter :/

Comment: It is one of those laws (or which there are many), which the government knows that, on it's face, it's hard to enforce. However, if you are a law abiding citizen, and you fail to disclose, you'll face the consequences of lying on an official form, and the attendant penalties (ban? I don't happen to know what they are.) If you are not, however, a LAC, and are caught performing some misdeeds, and it turns out that they (whomever they are) find out you were, indeed, in one of the proscribed countries; cont...

Comment: cont... it's another potential criminal charge they could levy against you, adding to your potential sentencing, in order to 'force' you to plea out by providing information on others. If, however, you are actually a terrorist, with terroristic nefarious thoughts and plans, you're more likely to either blow yourself up, or end up in the travel destination known as Guantanamo Bay....for life.... in a hole.... so, eh. Whether or not it is a 'good law' or an enforceable one, make absolutely no difference, in the end, does it. If you want to use the ESTA/VWP, you live by the rules as they are....

Comment: @MarkMayo my first response was that this is disgusting.  My more considered response is that it is sheer idiocy.  I've half a mind to start some sort of internet fund raising drive to pay the visa fees for those denied VWP travel under this new law.  I'll leave my earlier incorrect comment, in case anyone else happens upon the same VWP page that DHS has neglected to update.

Comment: I believe there's another interesting question here, which is "what if you are arriving by land?". In that case you don't have to get an ESTA, and I find it hard to imagine that every VWP arrival will be asked about their travels at the border. You could be admitted without having to lie at all.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't find it hard to believe.  It wouldn't be too hard for the agents to be instructed to ask "have you been to Iran, Iraq, etc., in the last five years."

Comment: My read of the links and related material suggests that the person is not BANNED, they simply cannot use the VWP.

Comment: There's also the question of what happens if one gets an ESTA and *then* goes to Iran. Technically speaking you might not have to lie at all, unless there's a second screening at the border.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34759/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-how-can-the-us-immigration-officials-know).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**There are several ways, but it doesn't really matter.**

First there are several ways US immigration can know these things. You might have been on a flight to the country in question. Or the US might find out from one of their intelligence partners. Your own country probably knows you made the visit, if you exited the country on your way there. But that's not the point of the exercise. They really don't care about someone who has visited Syria as a tourist.

The targets of this measure are people that the US suspects of having links to terrorism, but no real evidence. They know enough about those people to know that they have visited the countries in question, so they can't evade the measure by lying. People visiting these countries for legitimate reasons are just collateral damage.

The second point is that if you don't declare your visit on the ESTA, and US immigration knows or find out about it, you are guilty of lying on an immigration form. That's going to get your VWP privileges removed, and make it much harder for you to get a visa in the future. That's just fine by them as it gives them a reason to exclude someone acting suspiciously without needing any evidence of wrongdoing. Lying on an application form is a great way to get yourself in trouble.

Finally you ask "how could the US officials *prove* one has set foot in those countries". The answer to that is that they don't need to prove it. If they believe that you visited those countries and didn't say so, they can refuse you entry.

Comment: "Much harder to get a visa in the future": Wouldn't it more likely result in a ban?  Or is a ban only possible in the case of an overstay and a decision by an immigration judge?

Comment: @phoog I don't know enough to know if a ban is a possible repercussion. But a ban is a subset of it being 'harder to get a visa'.

Comment: That is certainly true.  It's worth noting that, regardless, "harder" in this case is likely to be a different order of magnitude than "hard" for someone who, say, appears to be an immigration risk.

Comment: There are still ways that one could get a visa despite a ban. I think "much harder" works.

Comment: So the answer is "If you're a bad guy, the US already knows you've been there. If not, they don't care about you"?

Comment: @JonathanReez Another possibility: you're a bad guy and the US doesn't know that yet, so they give you a B2 visa and let you into the US.  Most terrorists' budgets are probably large enough that a $160 visa fee plus incidental expenses doesn't pose much of an obstacle.  Neither is false documentation that would hide someone's travel history and/or nationality. I suppose the real point is to increase the chance that terrorists are individually screened though a visa application, which gives the US more of a chance to identify bad guys that they don't yet know about.

Comment: Making things harder on people who make tourist, business and family visits has the effect (considered beneficial by some) of deterring non-Americans who might make such a trip, so it causes further harm to the economies of the targeted countries, beyond non-extraterritorial US sanctions. It's more like collective punishment than collateral damage.

Comment: What if you travel on a different passport ?

Comment: I don't agree with the edit. Civil matters such as visas use a civil standard of proof--it has to be more likely that not that the person in question has visited the mentioned country. There is no way for the USA immigration authorities of knowing that unless there is a stamp in the passport or if that person is under surveillance.

Comment: @phoog The real purpose of these measures is the please the domestic US public by trying to show that they're doing something about terrorism and related immigration. These questions on the ESTA will do little is stopping any real terrorists. For that, they have other methods.

Comment: @uberque "civil standard of proof": maybe nominally, but in fact the only person the immigration officer has to prove it to is him- or herself.  VWP travelers waive the right to challenge the officer's decision.